# Prove $\Omega(f(n)) \subset \Omega(g(n)), iff : g(n)\in \mathcal{O}(f(n)) \wedge f(n) \not\in \mathcal{O}(g(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

I want to prove the following 
$$\Omega(f(n)) \subset \Omega(g(n)), iff  : g(n)\in \mathcal{O}(f(n)) \wedge f(n) \not\in \mathcal{O}(g(n))$$

What I did so far is:
$$t(n)\in\Omega(f(n)) \rightarrow \exists c_{1} \exists n_{0} \forall n>n_{0} , t(n)\geq c_{1}\cdot f(n)$$
Now I need to use the given details:
$$g(n)\in \mathcal{O}(f(n)) \rightarrow \exists c_{2} \exists n_{1} \forall n>n_{1} , g(n)\leq c_{2}\cdot f(n)$$

$$\frac{1}{c1}\cdot t(n) \geq f(n)$$
$$\frac{1}{c2}\cdot g(n) \leq f(n)$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{1}{c2}\cdot g(n)  \leq f(n) \leq  \frac{1}{c1}\cdot t(n) $$
$$\rightarrow t(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$$
I dont know how to continue and I dont know if its right
any suggestions?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with $f(n) \in \Omega(f(n))$. Since $\Omega(f(n)) \subset \Omega(g(n))$, we have $g(n) \in O(f(n))$ by partial ordering. You showed this correctly and more formally above. If you have already proven partial ordering of Big-O and Big-Omega, it's easier to use that.

Now, since $\Omega(f(n)) \subset \Omega(g(n))$, we let $j(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$ with $j(n) \not \in \Omega(f(n))$ by definition of a proper subset. And so since $j(n) \not \geq C * f(n)$ (for all $n \geq n_{0}$), we have $j(n) < C * f(n)$, which implies $j(n) \in O(f(n))$. And so we have this strict inequality that $c_{1} g(n) \leq j(n) < c_{2} f(n)$. Thus, $g(n) \not \in O(f(n))$.

I leave the other side for you.

Comment: How you can say that $j(n) \not\in \Omega(f(n)) $ its something we need to prove.. its not given.. right?

Comment: We're given $\Omega(f(n)) \subset \Omega(g(n))$. So by definition of a proper subset (note $\subset$ vs. $\subseteq$), we have such an element $j(n)$.

Comment: I know.. but how I can use it? this is what I need to prove, its not given to me , the only thing its given and I need to use its what after "$iff$"

Comment: what I wrote above it enough for the first side?

Comment: Which is exactly what I've done above. I'm just applying definitions. What does it mean for $j(n) \not \in \Omega(f(n))$? It means we can't have $j(n) \geq C * f(n)$ (for any $C$). So $j(n) < C * f(n)$. Now what is the definition of Big-O? I'm just applying that.

Comment: No, it is not enough for the first side. You're showing something trivial, which has already been given. You have to conclude that since $t(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$ that $g(n) \in O(f(n))$. I showed you how to do this.

Comment: $j(n) < C\cdot f(n) $ implies that its not $\in \mathcal{O}(f(n)) $ by definition  right? its need to be $\leq$ ..?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I dont understand you said we have $j(n) < C * f(n)$, which implies $j(n) \not \in O(f(n))$ how it can be? its implies that its $\in \mathcal{O}(f(n))$

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I've fixed that. Really what we have is $c_{1} * g(n) \leq j(n) < c_{2} * f(n)$. So we have a strict inequality that $g(n) \leq k * f(n)$. Can $f(n)$ then be in $O(g(n))$?

Comment: $g(n) \in \mathcal{O}(f(n)) $ not say that $f(n) \not\in \mathcal{O}(g(n))$

Comment: Since we have a strict inequality, can $f(n) \in O(g(n))$? That's the punchline.

Comment: OK Got it, the second side I start with $$t(n)\in \Omega(f(n))$$ and $$t(n)\in \Omega(g(n))$$?

Comment: You start with $g(n) \in \Omega(f(n))$ and $f(n) \not \in O(g(n))$. So you have $C * g(n) < f(n)$.

Comment: what about it: $$1.t(n)\in \Omega(f(n)), 2.t(n)\in \Omega(g(n))$$ so $$t(n)\geq c_{2}\cdot f(n), t(n) \geq c_{3}\cdot g(n)$$ now we have to cases to check one with $g(n)\geq f(n)$ and the opposite, now we can infer the two conditions.

Comment: You generally start with the assumptions. I think you're doing things the long way, and you're assuming a bit of what you're trying to prove. Start with the assumptions. What happens if $t(n) \in \Omega(f(n))$? What does this imply about $t(n)$ being in $\Omega(g(n))$? Now what happens if $C*g(n) < t(n) < f(n)$?